# Catch specific submitted form

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
...

$('form').submit(function(){
    ...
}
```

How can I adjust my code in order to catch only submitted **#my-modal** form? And not all kind of forms?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `$('#my-modal form').submit(...` or something more involved?

Comment: I think you should include some HTML. If '#my-modal' is a div that contains a form you could use: $('#my-modal > form').submit(...), but it all depends on your HTML

Comment: What Evan showed is okay for me. Thanks. I'm still novice with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-modal').find('form').submit(function() {

});
```

The jQuery find command looks only within the element so this would return only the form in your modal.